# Using CMFCPropertyPage in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, cmfcpropertypage

I can use the VS 2017 IDE to create a Dialog resource and then I go to add a class:

[image: Add Class]

I wanted to choose `CMFCPropertyPage` but it does not show. So is it Ok to just select `CPropertyPage` and then manually change it?

I am confused because it indicates here that I could select the class:

http://www.functionx.com/visualc/dialogboxes/mfcpspp.htm

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found out was that you need to be in the **ClassView** and not the **ResourceView**.

If you right-click a dialog resource to add a class you get a limited set of classes to derive from.

But if you right-click in the class view and select **Add Class** then you can create the class from `CMFCPropertyPage`.

I was surprised it did not create a empty dialog resource if it didn't exist though. And it was lacking the needed code. But I copied it over.

I know haw to do it now:

[image: Results]